# Why error handler is not catching any error in my angular 7 app?

Tags: angular

```
/** Add a product */
 addProduct(product: Product): Observable<Product> {
        var url = `${this.apiUrl}/Products`;
        return this.http.post<Product>(url, product).pipe(
          tap((newProduct: Product) => this.log(`added Product w/ id=${newProduct.id}`)),
          catchError(this.handleError<Product>('addProduct'))
        );
      }

 /**
   * Handle Http operation that failed.
   * Let the app continue.
   * @param operation - name of the operation that failed
   * @param result - optional value to return as the observable result
   */
  private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

      // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
      console.error(error); // log to console instead

      // TODO: better job of transforming error for user consumption
      this.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);

      // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
      return of(result);
    };
  }

  /** Log a ActionService message with the MessageService */
  private log(message: string) {
    console.log(message);
  }
```

I am using HttpInterceptor. Does it have to do with this which is preventing errors to be handled in service files? Should I handle errors per service file or through via common interceptor?

Comment: You might need to rethrow the error if you catch it in your HttpInterceptor

Comment: I have done that in the interceptor 
catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        return throwError(error);
      })

Comment: did you try to NOT use the HttpInterceptor ? to see if it is working vanilla?

Comment: The aim is NOT to remove the interceptor as its responsible for [toastr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toastr)  message. Even if its works that way, it's not of great use to me as I wanted to handle the error logging per service file.

Comment: Ofcourse you do but for the sake of the issue you can TRY